# Instagram Graph API - Mention API - Webhook how to test

Tags: php, instagram

I'm using a Webhook for Instagram Graph API's Mention API. I want to get a post request that contains `media_id` from Facebook Developer when my IG business account is mentioned by other users.
I have done all setting as described in Facebook Developer Document. And now I can send a test Request from Facebook Developer Webhook Dashboard by click Blue Button "Test". These reports' data is fake data, so I can not continue develop further logic. In order to receive real data, I used other ID account and tried to create an IG post which mentions my IG business account. But I get nothing. No request was sent to my Callback URL.

Can you tell me how to continue my development, get mentioned post and save this info into my database?

Comment: Please share some relevant code so that we can discuss what's wrong; it may also be helpful to show us the fake data and describe how it doesn't fit your needs

Comment: You should also give a link for "as described in Facebook Developer Document" so that others can reproduce your issue

Comment: @YakovL thank you for your interesting. I though I have no relevant Permission for this. So now i'm trying to use Tags API instead of Mention API.

Comment: my set-up hasn't worked either, is it because the app needs to be reviewed because it's using the manage_page permission that is only available after the review.

Comment: @zavr did you get it to work? Did you need to send the app for review?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck with the same thing. I can't continue any logic after this point! I'm not receiving anything on the webhook besides the test message. I think I've read everything I can on the internet of other people who have tried to make this work. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe we need a product review for certain permissions to actually test the mention webhooks live.

Such as:
instagram_basic
manage_pages

To get these, you would need to make a screencast of your application of why you would need the permissions. After you've set it up for review, I've heard other people say that it could take up to 4 months to get it reviewed.

The problem with the tags API is the resriction of replying to tags. Mentions are as far as I know, the only way to respond to users commenting you.

This is mostly all the info I could find, sorry if it isn't much...

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Where you able to solve it? Did you need any special permission? Did you need to send the app for review?

Answer (score 0):

When Business instagram user mentioned your IG Business account that time it will callback where as When Normal IG user mentioned it is not callback webhook

Comment: what why how do you know?